# How to make a call to the surveygizmo API to a specific page using python surveygizmo package?

Tags: python, survey

I downloaded the surveygizmo package (1.2.1) and easily did a call to surveygizmo API like this:

```
import surveygizmo as sg

client = sg.SurveyGizmo(
api_version='v4',
# example
api_token = "E4F796932C2743FEBF150B421BE15EB9",
api_token_secret = "A9fGMkJ5pJF1k"
)

surveys = client.api.survey.list()
print(surveys)
```

which results in something like this:

```
{'total_count': '8902', 
'total_pages': 179, 
'page': 1, # This is what I want to change
'results_per_page': 50, 
'data': [
    {'id': '7895426', 
        'team': '123456', 
        '_subtype': 'Standard Survey', 
        ... }, 
    {'id': '7895427', 
        'team': '123456', 
        '_subtype': 'Standard Survey', 
        ... },
    ...]}
```

How is it possible to access the following pages? I only see the first 50 results, which are all on the first page.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: You should consider hiding your `token` and `token_secret`

Comment: They aren't my real ones. I took the ones from https://pypi.python.org/pypi/SurveyGizmo/1.2.1.post1

Answer (score 1):

Via trial and error I found this solution:

```
surveys = client.api.survey.list(resultsperpage=500, page=5)
```

Answer (score 0):

I didn't take the time to set up access to SurveyGizmo. However, by importing the Python façade and poking around it and the documentation I found this possibility.

```
client.config.requests_kwargs={'page':2}
```

I'm curious to know whether it works.

Answer (score 0):

Genereally,  Anne suggested the best way I think but I can't vote because a newbie :)

I can only add that you may get total_pages as a variable and use it in loop.

```
total_pages = json.loads(sg.api.survey.list())['total_pages']
for numbe_page in range(1,total_pages):
     survey_list = json.loads(sg.api.survey.list(resultsperpage=500, page=number_page))
```

And some additional point

1) I found a [site with info about the parameters](https://support.klipfolio.com/hc/en-us/articles/215546358-Creating-a-SurveyGizmo-Data-Source) that helped me to find out about parameters working with sg.

2) And if you want to check available parameteres, you may look at code:  https://github.com/ITNG/SurveyGizmo/tree/master/surveygizmo/api

Answer (score 0):

Whenever I try to pull 40 or more results per page, and pull a specific page, the API times out. Is that not crazy? Seems like a terribly inefficient API.

```
survey_response = json.loads(client.api.surveyresponse.list(survey_id1, resultsperpage=30, page=1))
```

Answer (score 0):

Adding some modifications to the answers above, to save all responses in the survey you can do something like this:

```
client = SurveyGizmo(
    api_version='v4',

    # example token from SurveyGizmo docs
    api_token="E4F796932C2743FEBF150B421BE15EB9",
    api_token_secret="A9fGMkJ5pJF1k"

)

client.config.api_token = "your API token"
client.config.api_token_secret = "your API token secret"

survey_id = "your survey ID"

responses = client.api.surveyresponse.list(survey_id)

pages = responses['total_pages']

data = []

for page in range(1, pages):
    print('Getting page {}/{}'.format(page, pages))
    data.append(client.api.surveyresponse.list(id, page=page))

filename = 'data.json'.format(time)
with open(filename, 'w', encoding='utf-8') as f:
    json.dump(data, f, ensure_ascii=False, indent=4)
```